Doesn't change the parameter in Unity FMOD
I encountered a problem that when changing the value of a parameter through the code, nothing happens. The parameter stops changing after the player moves to another scene.
Here is the script that should change the value of the parameter when the player touches the trigger.
public class ChangeAmbient : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float parameterValue;
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        ChangeAmbientParameter(parameterValue, other);
    }
    private void ChangeAmbientParameter(float _parameterValue, Collider collider)
    {
        if (collider != null)
        {
            if (collider.CompareTag("Player"))
            {
                AudioManager.instance.SetAmbienceParameter("area", _parameterValue);
            }
        }
    }
}

Sound Manager:
public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<EventInstance> eventInstances;
    private List<StudioEventEmitter> eventEmitters;

    private EventInstance ambienceEventInstance;

    public static AudioManager instance { get; private set; }
    private void Awake()
    {
        if (instance != null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Found more AM");
        }

        instance = this;

    public void InitializeAmbience(EventReference ambienceEventReference)
    {
        ambienceEventInstance = CreateInstance(ambienceEventReference);
        ambienceEventInstance.start();
    }

    public void SetAmbienceParameter(string parameterName, float parameterValue)
    {
        ambienceEventInstance.setParameterByName(parameterName, parameterValue);
    }

    public EventInstance CreateInstance(EventReference eventReference)
    {
        EventInstance eventInstance = RuntimeManager.CreateInstance(eventReference);
        eventInstances.Add(eventInstance);
        return eventInstance;
    }
}

The sound is initialized on a separate object on the stage.
public class InitializeAmbient : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        AudioManager.instance.InitializeAmbience(FMODEvents.instance.windAmbience);
    }
}


Have you debugged to find out what exactly is not being called as expected?

@derHugo No errors come out, everything works except changing parameters. I made it so that when the script starts, after the initialization of the sound, immediately after it changed the value of the parameter, and it worked. But if you change the parameter using a trigger, nothing changes.                                            public void Start()     {         InitializeAmbience(FMODEvents.instance.windAmbience);  SetAmbienceParameter("area", 1)     }

Again have you put some debug logs or breakpoints to see whether the expected lines of code are executed at all?

@derHugo That's the thing, nothing happens, everything works fine except for the parameters themselves. The sound is initialized, but to check if the sound reference is in ambienceEventInstance is impossible, because the FMOD plugin is not displayed in the Unity inspector.

But you are sure the line of code for setting the parameters is executed as expected? Please do some Debugging .. beyond that .. if you think the issue is with the plugin itself it is always best to directly file a bug report at the authors of the plugin rather than asking us here who don't have any insights into the plugin either ;)

I found what the problem was. The thing is that in addition to the wind sound I initialized another sound into the same variable and replaced it. Problem solved.
